# Create sliding logos in multiple rows

Tags: editing

I'm very new to creating videos and I want to create 3-4 rows of brand logos that are sliding right to left at a constant rate - not moving and stopping. There'll be limited logos so I want them to loop around if that's possible. The closest thing I've found as a reference is this: https://demo.essentialplugin.com/prodemo/pro-logo-showcase-responsive-slider/logo-slider-with-multi-row/

Can this be done with Adobe premiere or after effects? A detailed guide would be appreciated since I'm new to this.

Comment: exactly how many logos do you have to work with?

Comment: There are around 9 logos in a row. 5 logos are visible at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Gridder script](https://aescripts.com/gridder/) for After Effects might be useful for this.

There's a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHaO8nw9QJI) showing how to use it.

If you're new to After Effects, [this set of tutorials](https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/) is old but good.